communicate btw two apps on different pc over lan in tauri
I have created Desktop application for Windows using the taur, now I want to sync data across the multiple applications running over different PCs, which are connected through LAN. so each application can have the latest copy of data. How can I do it. is there any tauri plugin available for this?
